# Ruby AWS SDK breaks when caching classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm having a headache trying to figure this out.
Everytime i try to deploy my app into productio i get this error:

```
/Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/service_interface.rb:24:in `module_eval': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/client/xml.rb:29:in `<module:XML>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/client/xml.rb:19:in `<class:Client>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/client/xml.rb:16:in `<class:SimpleEmailService>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/client/xml.rb:15:in `<module:AWS>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/client/xml.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from (eval):1:in `configure_client'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:484:in `module_eval'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:484:in `configure_client'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/configured_client_methods.rb:27:in `configure_client'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/client.rb:32:in `<class:Client>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/client.rb:18:in `<class:SimpleEmailService>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/client.rb:15:in `<module:AWS>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/client.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/errors.rb:20:in `<module:Errors>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/errors.rb:18:in `<class:SimpleEmailService>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/errors.rb:15:in `<module:AWS>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service/errors.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from (eval):1:in `included'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/service_interface.rb:24:in `module_eval'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/service_interface.rb:24:in `included'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service.rb:146:in `include'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service.rb:146:in `<class:SimpleEmailService>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service.rb:136:in `<module:AWS>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/simple_email_service.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/rails.rb:157:in `block in add_action_mailer_delivery_method'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:746:in `<class:Base>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActionMailer>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `const_get'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-3.0.0/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:434:in `eager_load!'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/Rafael/Dev/Nuveo/StoresEngine/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/Rafael/Dev/Nuveo/StoresEngine/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /Users/Rafael/Dev/Nuveo/StoresEngine/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/Rafael/Dev/Nuveo/StoresEngine/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/Rafael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

But if i disable the config.cache_classes setting it to false, the error wont show up anymore.
But there is no way that im leaving cache_classes = false into production.

Can someone help me with this?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you aware that the SDK is at `1.15` now, and you're on `1.3.9` *(1-2 years old)*? Mixing that with Rails `3.2.13` may not be the best idea; I'd start with upgrading to the latest SDK release.

Comment: Just old GEM! Thanks for the reply! Somehow my bundle update have not been as successful as i expected. :)

Comment: Good for you; glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS SDK was out of date.
Updating it solved the hole trouble :)
Thanks Deefour